# How to make a reference to a method name on an interface strongly typed

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, strongly-typed-view, strong-typing

Sorry if this has been answered already, but I think I actually lack the formal education to ask this question properly, and hence also lack the correct criteria to search for it successfully.

I have an API that has several calls that do almost the same thing, but act on different input objects using a different method, but always form the same interface. I want to take the cut & paste aspect out of the API method call processes so that the common code gets done the same in all method invocations. I have managed to get a working solution using generics for the input and output objects and am making a reference to the method-name to be invoked from a string. I would like references to the the methods to be strongly typed instead of string based, so that a rename of the method name when re-factoring would not potentially leave the "magic" string of the method name waiting to explode at run-time.

Below is a very simplified version of what I am trying to achieve.

```
class ARequest { };
class AResponse { };
class BRequest { };
class BResponse { };

interface IWorker
{
    AResponse DoA(ARequest aRequest);
    BResponse DoB(BRequest bRequest);
}
class Worker : IWorker
{
    public AResponse DoA(ARequest aRequest)
    {
        return new AResponse();
    }
    public BResponse DoB(BRequest bRequest)
    {
        return new BResponse();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // current concrete copy & paste implementation
        var a1 = API.DoA(new ARequest { });
        var b1 = API.DoB(new BRequest { });
        // new generic implementation
        var a2 = API.DoA2(new ARequest { });
        var b2 = API.DoB2(new BRequest { });
    }
}

static class API
{
    // current concrete copy & paste implementation
    public static AResponse DoA(ARequest aRequest)
    {
        // lots of common code for logging & preperation
        var worker = GetWorker();
        return worker.DoA(aRequest);
    }
    public static BResponse DoB(BRequest bRequest)
    {
        // lots of common code for logging & preperation
        var worker = GetWorker();
        return worker.DoB(bRequest);
    }
    private static IWorker GetWorker()
    {
        return new Worker();
    }
    // new generic implementation Attempt
    public static AResponse DoA2(ARequest aRequest)
    {
        return DoGen<ARequest, AResponse>(aRequest, "DoA"); // how to make references to DoA and DoB methods on the IWorker strongly typed?
    }
    public static BResponse DoB2(BRequest bRequest)
    {
        return DoGen<BRequest, BResponse>(bRequest, "DoB"); // how to make references to DoA and DoB methods on the IWorker strongly typed?
    }
    public static TResponse DoGen<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest requestObj, string methodname)
        where TRequest : class
        where TResponse : class
    {
        // lots of common code for logging & preperation
        var worker = GetWorker();
        var mi = worker.GetType().GetMethod(methodname);
        var result = mi.Invoke(worker, new Object[] { requestObj });
        return result as TResponse;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are the response types related in any way?

Comment: Take a look at this blog post, it describes a model that does what you need: http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92

Comment: Foo42: They have some common fields in the final implementation that are from a common base class. In the example they are not related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"magic" string of the method name change to delegate on delegate

```
  public static AResponse DoA2(ARequest aRequest)
  {
    return DoGen<ARequest, AResponse>(aRequest, worker => worker.DoA);
  }
  public static BResponse DoB2(BRequest bRequest)
  {
    return DoGen<BRequest, BResponse>(bRequest, worker => worker.DoB); 
  }
  public static TResponse DoGen<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest requestObj, 
       Func<IWorker, Func<TRequest, TResponse>> methodRef)
    where TRequest : class
    where TResponse : class
  {
    // lots of common code for logging & preparation 
    var worker = GetWorker();
    var method = methodRef(worker);

    return method(requestObj);
  }
```

Comment: That is (as far as I can tell anyway) doing exactly what I wanted. Now I just need to learn what it is doing. I guess it is time to stop shying away from functors.

Answer (score 1):

Func< xRequest, xResponse > might do what you are looking for:

```
        var a1 = new Func<ARequest, AResponse>(API.DoA);
        var b1 = new Func<BRequest, BResponse>(API.DoB);
        var a2 = new Func<ARequest, AResponse>(API.DoA2);
        var b2 = new Func<BRequest, BResponse>(API.DoB2);
        a1.Invoke(new ARequest { });
        b1.Invoke(new BRequest { });
        a2.Invoke(new ARequest { });
        b2.Invoke(new ARequest { }); // fails at compile time
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a delegate for the mehods:

```
    public delegate TResponse DoXDelegate<in TRequest, out TResponse>(TRequest request);

    public static TResponse DoGen<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest requestObj, DoXDelegate<TRequest, TResponse> method)
        where TRequest : class
        where TResponse : class
    {
        // lots of common code for logging & preperation
        var worker = GetWorker();
        /*var mi = worker.GetType().GetMethod(methodname);
        var result = mi.Invoke(worker, new Object[] { requestObj });
        return result as TResponse;*/
        return method.Invoke(requestObj);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this would be called? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Sorry, from reading the other answers I think i got it wrong. Stick with the answer of DarkGray.

Answer (score 0):

Use *`Func<TRequest, TResponse>`* like so:

**Edit:** That solution example is only usable if it doesn't matter where worker object comes from.

```
// new generic implementation Attempt
public static AResponse DoA2(ARequest aRequest)
{
  return DoGen<ARequest, AResponse>(aRequest, DoA); // how to make refreces to DoA and DoB methods strongly typed?
}

public static BResponse DoB2(BRequest bRequest)
{
  return DoGen<BRequest, BResponse>(bRequest, DoB); // how to make refreces to DoA and DoB methods strongly typed?
}

public static TResponse DoGen<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest requestObj, Func<TRequest, TResponse> func)
  where TRequest : class
  where TResponse : class
{
  // lots of common code for logging & preperation
  var result = func(requestObj);
  return result as TResponse;
}
```

Comment: Would that not be using the DoA and DoB methods of the API, instead of the ones on the worker object? The desired effect is to invoke the methods on the worker object.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. I thought *API.DoA* is already *static* and already calls *GetWorker()*. So it is not needed to call a second *GetWorker()* in *DoGen(...)* method.

Comment: I explained it badly: The problem with DoA and DoB is that they are "cut and paste" implementations of each other with just the method name on the worker changed. DoA2 and DoB2 are meant to invoke a generic method that does all the common parts in one place, with the only differentiation being the method on the IWorker interface that is invoked, the input object types, and the output object type.

Comment: @MyOtherMe Now I understand. I just read that DarkGray's answer works for you. So I could delete my answer. Is the deletion ok for you?

Comment: I don't mind if you delete, but I think you will loose reputation if you delete it. And your answer might help someone else solve the problem and distinguish between the different scenarios.